# Search and replace http:// links to https:// to get the green padlock

Tags: ssl

I've got a WordPress CMS and I have a few `http` URLs that aren't being converted to `https`. I've installed the `SSL Insecure Content Fixer` plugin but that didn't do anything. I also have the code below in the `.htaccess` file which didn't convert the URLs that are showing up on view source:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

For some reason some of the menu items that are in `https` form are being displayed as `http`.

In this case, should I search and replace instances in the MySQL database from `http` to `https`? Or is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Hi unixmiah, welcome to WPSE. Just so you know, plugin recommendations are off-topic here so I've removed the part of your question that asks for a plugin. Do feel free to [take our tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site!

Comment: downvoted as "something is not working" without details, is not a question that can be answered.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I have to clear up my question. I stopped installing the url converter plugins. it never worked when i tried in the past, like last summer. I had better luck doing search and replace in mysql .sql file then reuploading the file with better luck i was able to do what i intended to do.

Comment: @unixmiah, can you please add an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this problem in the past. In my opinion, the easiest way is by making use of the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/

Always perform a backup of your database before performing a search and replace. Make sure you do a "Dry Run" first. If you do not already have good backup procedures in place, check out UpdraftPlus.

Comment: that didn't do anything. I tried searching and replacing a url, it didn't take changes to affect.

Comment: I did this for http:// to https:// and it grew my database from 118mb to 1,000+mb.  The host doesn't like it and neither do I.  But I'm sure there's a very good reason, perhaps regex or something needs to be used.  Does anyone else have this issue?